# how to create django custom filefield to upload to amazon s3 with specfic bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have a few Amazon S3 Bucket, i would like to create multiple file field that save to respective bucket

i've read about creating a storage class and use  S3Boto3Storage, however this require specification of Bucket name at settings level, i'm not able to set different bucket for different use case, example below:

```
class AmazonS3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):

    def get_available_name(self, name, max_length=None):
        return name
```

Anyone have solution to this?

Comment: refer this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution. I found out in S3Boto3Storage there's a **'bucket_name'** property, i can state bucket_name when extending S3Boto3Storage

```
class CustomStorageBucket1(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = "your_bucket_name_1"

class CustomStorageBucket2(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = "your_bucket_name_2"
```

**within Model**

```
test_image = models.ImageField(storage=CustomStorageBucket1(),
                                        upload_to='/test', max_length=50)
```